# How to load products from a specific category based on special price availability?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.4

I have following code

```
$promoCatId = (int)Mage::getStoreConfig('promoprodsec/promoprodgroup/promocategoryid');

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId($store)->load($promoCatId)
    ->getProductCollection();

$allProductsInPromoCategory = $products->getAllIds();
```

It gives me all the products of $promoCatId category.

Now I want to get all the products which are not having special price or the special price date range has expired from all the products of  `$allProductsInPromoCategory`

How can I accomplish this without using foreach loop and again loading every product collection again?

```
foreach ($allProductsInPromoCategory as $promoprod) {
    Mage:getModel('catalog/product')->load( $promoprod);

    //do validation for the special price criteria
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you state `->getProductCollection()` on your category, you end up with a object of type `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection`, which is basically a product collection like all the other.

Since this collection is an **EAV** collection, you can filter it with the help of the function `addAttributeToFilter`

And since you actually want an `OR` (`where special price is null or special to date <= now()`), you want your two conditions to be in the same `addAttributeToFilter`

So I would say you can achieve this by doing :

```
$promoCatId  = (int)Mage::getStoreConfig('promoprodsec/promoprodgroup/promocategoryid');

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                ->setStoreId($store)
                ->load(promoCatId)
                ->getProductCollection()
                ->addAttributeToFilter(
                    array(
                        array('attribute' => 'special_price', 'null' => true),
                        array('attribute' => 'special_from_date', 'lt' => Mage::getModel('core/date')->date(Varien_Date::DATETIME_PHP_FORMAT))
                    )
                );

$allProductsInPromoCategory = $products->getAllIds();

echo $products->getSelect();
```

### Useful to know :

- I am actually using `Mage::getModel('core/date')->date(Varien_Date::DATETIME_PHP_FORMAT)` to get the current date relative to the configured locale timezone of the store
- `echo $products->getSelect();` on a collection will display you the query done by Magento, really useful to actually see if the where is what you really want it to be. In my case it displays :

> SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`,
>   `at_special_price`.`value` AS `special_price`,
>   IF(at_special_from_date.value_id > 0, at_special_from_date.value,
>   at_special_from_date_default.value) AS `special_from_date` FROM
>   `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN
>   `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON
>   cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND
>   cat_index.category_id = '15' INNER JOIN
>   `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `at_special_price` ON
>   (`at_special_price`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND
>   (`at_special_price`.`attribute_id` = '76') AND
>   (`at_special_price`.`store_id` = 0) INNER JOIN
>   `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS
>   `at_special_from_date_default` ON
>   (`at_special_from_date_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`)
>   AND (`at_special_from_date_default`.`attribute_id` = '77') AND
>   `at_special_from_date_default`.`store_id` = 0 LEFT JOIN
>   `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `at_special_from_date` ON
>   (`at_special_from_date`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND
>   (`at_special_from_date`.`attribute_id` = '77') AND
>   (`at_special_from_date`.`store_id` = 1) WHERE
>   ((at_special_price.value IS NULL) OR (IF(at_special_from_date.value_id
>   > 0, at_special_from_date.value, at_special_from_date_default.value) < '2016-01-08 22:05:14'))

Comment: thanks for your reply, It gave me the idea to correct my approach, though I used a different way.